# Tensorflow batch normalization

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

Below are the code i am using as a learning programming in Tensorflow.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import datetime
import time, os

import tensorflow as tf

# Import data
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epoch = 5
batch_size = 128
display_step = 10
model_path = "./output/model.ckpt"
logs_path = './logs'

directory = os.path.dirname(model_path)
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)

directory = os.path.dirname(logs_path)
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)

# Network Parameters
n_input = 784 # data input
n_classes = 10 # classes
dropout = 0.5 # Dropout, probability to keep units
l2_regularization_strength = 0.0005 #l2 regularization strength

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input], name='InputData')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes], name='LabelData')
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) #dropout (keep probability)
mode = tf.placeholder(tf.int32);

# Create some wrappers for simplicity
def conv2d(x, kernel_shape, strides=1, mode=0):
    # Conv2D wrapper, with batch normalization and relu activation
    weights = tf.get_variable('weights', kernel_shape, initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())

    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, weights, strides=[1, strides, strides, 1], padding='SAME')
    pop_mean = tf.get_variable('bn_pop_mean', [x.get_shape()[-1]], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0), trainable=False)
    pop_var = tf.get_variable('bn_pop_var', [x.get_shape()[-1]], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1), trainable=False)
    scale = tf.get_variable('bn_scale', [x.get_shape()[-1]], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1))
    beta = tf.get_variable('bn_beta', [x.get_shape()[-1]], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0))
    epsilon = 1e-3
    decay = 0.999
    if mode == 0:
        batch_mean, batch_var = tf.nn.moments(x,[0, 1, 2])
        train_mean = tf.assign(pop_mean, pop_mean * decay + batch_mean * (1 - decay))
        train_var = tf.assign(pop_var, pop_var * decay + batch_var * (1 - decay))
        with tf.control_dependencies([train_mean, train_var]):
            bn = tf.nn.batch_normalization(x, batch_mean, batch_var, beta, scale, epsilon, name='bn')
    else:
        bn = tf.nn.batch_normalization(x, pop_mean, pop_var, beta, scale, epsilon, name='bn')

    return tf.nn.relu(bn, name = 'relu')


def maxpool2d(x, k=2):
    # MaxPool2D wrapper
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1], padding='SAME', name='maxpool')

# Create model
def conv_net(x, dropout, mode):
    # Reshape input picture
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])

    with tf.variable_scope("conv1"):
        # Convolution Layer
        conv1 = conv2d(x, [5, 5, 1, 32], mode=mode)
        # Max Pooling (down-sampling)
        conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)

    with tf.variable_scope("conv2"):
        # Convolution Layer
        conv2 = conv2d(conv1, [5, 5, 32, 64], mode=mode)
        # Max Pooling (down-sampling)
        conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)

    with tf.variable_scope("fc1"):
        # Fully connected layer
        # Reshape conv2 output to fit fully connected layer input
        weights = tf.get_variable("weights", [7*7*64, 1024], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
        biases = tf.get_variable("biases", [1024], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
        fc1 = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, weights.get_shape().as_list()[0]])
        fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights), biases)
        fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1, name = 'relu')

        # Apply Dropout
        fc1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, dropout, name='dropout')

    with tf.variable_scope("output"):
        # Output, class prediction
        weights = tf.get_variable("weights", [1024, n_classes], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
        biases = tf.get_variable("biases", [n_classes], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
        out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights), biases)
    return out

with tf.name_scope('Model'):
    # Construct model
    pred = conv_net(x, keep_prob, mode)

with tf.name_scope('Loss'):
    # Define loss and optimizer
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))

    vars   = tf.trainable_variables()
    l2_regularization = tf.add_n([tf.nn.l2_loss(v) for v in vars if any(x in v.name for x in ['weights', 'biases'])])
    for v in vars:
        if any(x in v.name for x in ['weights', 'biases']):
            print(v.name + '-included!')
        else:
            print(v.name)

    cost += l2_regularization_strength*l2_regularization

with tf.name_scope('Optimizer'):
    # Define optimizer
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)

    # Op to calculate every variable gradient
    grads = tf.gradients(cost, tf.trainable_variables())
    grads = list(zip(grads, tf.trainable_variables()))

    # Op to update all variables according to their gradient
    apply_grads = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=grads)

with tf.name_scope('Accuracy'):
    # Evaluate model
    correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# Create a summary to monitor cost tensor
tf.scalar_summary('cost', cost)
# Create a summary to monitor l2_regularization tensor
tf.scalar_summary('l2_regularization', l2_regularization)
# Create a summary to monitor accuracy tensor
tf.scalar_summary('accuracy', accuracy)
# Create summaries to visualize weights
for var in tf.trainable_variables():
    tf.histogram_summary(var.name, var)
for var in tf.all_variables():
    if 'bn_pop' in var.name:
        tf.histogram_summary(var.name, var)
# Summarize all gradients
for grad, var in grads:
    tf.histogram_summary(var.name + '/gradient', grad)
# Merge all summaries into a single op
merged_summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()

# 'Saver' op to save and restore all the variables
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    step = 1

    # op to write logs to Tensorboard
    summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(logs_path, graph=tf.get_default_graph())

    # Keep training until reach max epoch
    while step * batch_size < training_epoch * mnist.train.num_examples:
        start_time = time.time()
        # Get barch
        batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
        # Run optimization op (backprop)
        sess.run(apply_grads, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y, keep_prob: dropout, mode: 0})
        duration = time.time() - start_time
        if step % display_step == 0:
            # Calculate batch loss and accuracy
            loss, acc, summary = sess.run([cost, accuracy, merged_summary_op], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                              y: batch_y,
                                                              keep_prob: 1.,
                                                              mode: 1})

            # Write logs at every iteration
            summary_writer.add_summary(summary, step)

            # Calculate number sample per sec
            samples_per_sec = batch_size / duration
            format_str = ('%s: Iter %d, Epoch %d, (%.1f examples/sec; %.3f sec/batch), Minibatch Loss = %.5f , Training Accuracy=%.5f')
            print (format_str % (datetime.now(), step*batch_size, int(step*batch_size/mnist.train.num_examples) + 1, samples_per_sec, float(duration), loss, acc))
        step += 1
    print("Optimization Finished!")

    # Calculate accuracy for 256 mnist test images
    print("Testing Accuracy:", \
        sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images[:5000],
                                      y: mnist.test.labels[:5000],
                                      keep_prob: 1.,
                                      mode: 2}))

    # Save model weights to disk
    save_path = saver.save(sess, model_path)
    print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
```

When i open the tensorboard and look at the histogram and distribution sesstion, the 'bn_pop_mean' and 'bn_pop_var' in 'conv1' and 'conv2' are not updateing (they are constant at the initialised value).

Although after the training i achieved around 97% accuracy, i don't know if it the batch normalization is in effect.

Answer (score 1):

In your conv_net function, you didn't set the "reuse" parameter for the [tf.variable_scope()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#variable_scope). The default setting for "reuse" is "None". Every time conv2d function is called, "bn_pop_mean" and "bn_pop_var" are re-initalized.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if mode == 0:
        batch_mean, batch_var = tf.nn.moments(x,[0, 1, 2])
        train_mean = tf.assign(pop_mean, pop_mean * decay + batch_mean * (1 - decay))
        train_var = tf.assign(pop_var, pop_var * decay + batch_var * (1 - decay))
        with tf.control_dependencies([train_mean, train_var]):
            bn = tf.nn.batch_normalization(x, batch_mean, batch_var, beta, scale, epsilon, name='bn')
    else:
        bn = tf.nn.batch_normalization(x, pop_mean, pop_var, beta, scale, epsilon, name='bn')
```

It seems that the `if` prediction here always evaluate to be `False`. I guess what you want to do is using `mode` via `feed_dict` to control your batch normalization. So you should use `tf.cond` in TensorFlow instead of `if` in Python.